# uiimage apply filters like TOPAZ plugin in photoshop

Tags: iphone, uiimage, photoshop, effects, gpuimage

I need suggestions over how can i apply filters like topaz plugin in photoshop to my uiimage
in iphone application. I dont even know whether it is possible or not. Is this possible using coreimage framework. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at GPU framework. [link](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: @SuryaSubenthiran thanks buddy. kind of helped but not exactly what i need